# YouTube Videos are not displayed correctly in android , IOS Mobile devices

Tags: jquery, html

I have used the below code to embed you tube videos, Iframe tag not loaded videos in mobile device.

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head><title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <iframe width="853" height="480" src="http://www.youtube.com/v/RaQV6iQwC7Y?version=3&amp;autohide=1&amp;autoplay=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="">
    </iframe>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Please suggest me how to display youtube videos for IOS, android, tablet and desktop browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the Youtube guide to embed Youtube videos on a page: https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters

I typically use the YT API for embedding videos but to handle videos on iOS devices, I use the iFrame embed code, like below:

```
<iframe width="width here" height="height here" border="0" src=' + ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https' : 'http') + '://www.youtube.com/embed/' + VIDEOID here + '&autoplay=1&showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: thanks @kayen.
if I use src http://www.youtube.com/embed/u1zgFlCw8Aw?autoplay=1 video file is loaded. Is this solution that works on all devices including desktop and tablet ?

Comment: Yeah, this works on the iPhone, iPad and android devices, invoking their native player for playing videos. It works pretty darn well on desktops as well!